# Controlling the Size of an Open Cover of a Set of Measure Zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ of Lebesgue measure zero contained in a compact interval, say $[0,1]$.  We know that since $A$ has measure zero we can cover $A$ with a countable set of open intervals, say $\{U_i\}$, such that $\mu(\cup_iU_i)\leq \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon$.  Now, if we fix some $\varepsilon>0$, can we cover $A$ with a countable set of open intervals, say now $\{V_i\}$, such that $\mu(V_i)\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2^i}$ for each $i$?  That is, can we control the size of each individual set in some way? I have been thinking about this for a bit, and keep running into having to do things an infinite number of times, or having to choose the wrong indices first.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have been told of, though have not been shown, a counterexample for a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R^2}$ which is not contained in a compact set.  So maybe this holds only if $A$ is contained in a compact set, or if $A$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.  Any stronger or weaker result would be wonderful as well, or just a hint.

Comment: @JBeards: I think it would help to clarify your post along the lines of Arturo's comment on user9176's answer.  You currently have $\varepsilon$ ambiguously quantified.

Comment: @Jonas: I did what I could, but I'm struggling to see how this could be misinterpreted.

Comment: One idea I have is to choose $\{V_i^1\}$ such that $\mu(\cup_iV_i^1)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ then choose one element from there.  Now, choose  $\{V_i^2\}$ such that $\mu(\cup_iV_i^2)<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ and choose an element from there, repeating for every natural number.  However, I'm not sure the set I end up with will cover $A$.

Comment: @JBeardz: It does not have to, even if $A$ is a two-element set.

Comment: Whoops, that's obvious.  I forgot to add that at each step, you take a cover of $A$ minus the part you just covered, since that will still be of measure zero.  In the case of a two-element set, this resolves this issue.  Sorry, important point that I forgot to mention.

Comment: It feels to me that if there is a counter-example, it would be the Cantor set on [0,1].  Not sure why that feels right, but it does.

Comment: @Thomas: Sure.  The Cantor set ends up being a counter example to everything.  I haven't spent much time looking at it in this case, because I feel like my statement should be true, and I don't really like the Cantor set.  But maybe I need to spend some time with it.

Comment: @JBeardz: This will not work either, though a variant might. Look for example at the rationals in the unit interval. The first choice of interval might be $(1/4,3/4)$. That leaves a bunch of stuff uncovered. Take a cover of this of small total length, and choose the second interval to be in the top half, and keep on doing this. The procedure will never include anything $\le 1/4$.

Comment: @user6312: Thanks, good point.

Comment: I'm wondering if the rationals may provide a counterexample.

Comment: @JBeardz: A counterexample will have to be uncountable.  If the set were $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$, you could let $V_i$ be an interval of length $\epsilon2^{-i}$ containing $a_i$.

Comment: Oh lord, what a vast oversight.  I remember realizing this earlier.  Please excuse me, haha.  I am sitting at home sick, coughing up my lungs.

Comment: Well, I guess a counterexample would be required to be uncountably infinite (because a countable set always has such a cover) and the compactness of the Cantor set means that any such cover must have a finite sub-cover.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the property holds, then $A$ has [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) $0$, because $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}\right)^d=\frac{\varepsilon^d}{2^d-1}$$ can be made arbitrarily small for each fixed $d>0$ by choosing $\varepsilon$ small enough.  The Cantor set has Lebesgue measure $0$ and Hausdorff dimension $\log_3(2)$, so it is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked more carefully at the Cantor Set.